# How to combine FOR and UNTIL in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to write a batch script that will loop through a list of file names and:

1. Attempt to create that file
2. Check if the creation was successful, and if not, try again after a few seconds

This is as far as I've gotten, which borrows from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906705/loop-until-file-exists-using-windows-batch-command). However, it will only check and create file1.txt, not file2.txt or file3.txt. Then it will create a file "%A". Why is it only looping through the first file, and where is "%A" coming from?

I assume it is something to do with how I'm using the variable %A. Especially because if I manually type this out in the command prompt, instead of a batch file, and using %A instead of %%A, it works correctly.

```
FOR %%A IN ("file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3txt") DO (
:Check
IF EXIST %%A GOTO Found

ECHO NotFound: %%A

echo.>%%A

timeout /t 5

GOTO Check

:Found
ECHO Found: %%A

)
```

Comment: You cannot use GOTO and labels within a `FOR` command.  It breaks out of the `FOR` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `CALL` command to essentially work like a Function. When you use `CALL` the code execution will return to the original spot in the code it was called from and continue on.

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN ("file1.txt" "file2.txt" "file3txt") DO (
    CALL :CHECK "%%~A"
)

GOTO :EOF
REM Functions only below this line
:Check

IF EXIST "%~1" (
    ECHO Found: %~1
) ELSE (
    ECHO NotFound: %~1
    timeout /t 5
    GOTO Check
)
GOTO :EOF
```